# Is there an alternative to OCLE 2.0?

Tags: uml, diagram, ocl

In this "CASE Instruments" course the teacher said this software "[OCLE 2.0](http://lci.cs.ubbcluj.ro/ocle/)" is the only software that can validate and compile UML. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You need to query Google. On SO your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

'Compile UML' is an unclear term. Many tools support selective code generation for some UML facilities. Probably no tools support abstract concepts such as Use Cases.

The Eclipse Papyrus/UML2/OCL/EMF combination has powerful capabilities including generation of inline Java code for arbitrary OCL. Since the Pivot-based Eclipse OCL prototypes solutions to many problems with the OCL specification such as templates and stereotypes, I doubt you will find a better solution. I have certainly heard comments that Eclipse OCL is the only solution that comes close.

Dan Chiorean, the boss of OCLE, used to be a regular contributor at the annual OCL workshops. Since he has been quiet recently, I assumed that OCLE had gone quiet too. The OCLE website does not have any dates or OCL or UML versions, but its first overview sentence

> Look at the UML specification! All the UML diagrams are carefully designed and represented using UML CASE Tools. Unfortunately, the UML static semantics expressed using OCL has many syntactical, semantical and conceptual errors.

suggests that it was written before UML 2.5 for which Eclipse OCL was used to eliminate the prolific problems in earlier versions.

Comment: Did a Google search. The most recent release of OCLE was 2005, so sadly rather mature.